# Conv Net Model is overfitting

Tags: classification, cnn, overfitting, audio-recognition

So I made a convolution neural network to classify between different phonemes. My input datasets are a series of 0.4-second long spectrograms, the labels are each an individual phoneme that happens at every 1/100th of a second. So a 10-second long video would have 1000 labels.

If I pick frame 100, the input would be a spectrogram starting from frame 80 and ending at frame 120. The longest phoneme lasts for 20 frames but the extra length is kept for context.

The structure of the model is one convolution layer with 30 filters, RELU, max-pooling, and finally one fully-connected layer to act as the output layer. There is also a 35% drop-out on the convolution layer.

My dataset is a 26-minute video of me speaking the first third of the sponge bob movie script (not very professional, I know).

I used incremental learning by splitting the dataset into 1-minute pieces. For each training iteration, it made 10 batches, with each batch being 64 random frames from 1 specific minute of the dataset. If the model got above 70% on one 'minute', and the model accuracy didn't change by over 3% within 30 batches, it moved on to the next minute. Unfortunately, even if the model got around 70% on the training data, it still underperformed on the testing data as it consistently got around 30%.

I have run out of ideas to solve this sever overfitting problem, any suggestions would help.

Comment: Instead of just one convolutional layer, I'd stack multiple ones and instead of the fully connected one, I'd use a bottleneck layer (1x1 Conv with desired number of classes as number of filters) and then GlobalAveragePooling (GAP), as it is used in fully convolutional networks (FCN). Especially the bottleneck+GAP approach seems to avoid overfitting much better than a fully connected layer. See e.g. https://cpjku.github.io/dcase_task2/ for a description of a fully convolutional architecture (for general sound tagging).

Comment: Would you suggest for me to add residual learning as well?

Comment: Residual connections might help you to learn a little better and a little faster with fewer parameters. But IMHO they won’t help much with overfitting. I’d first try to get it to work without them.

Comment: Thanks, last question. Whenever I add softmax to the fully connected layer, the model get's the exact same loss and accuracy after every training batch and does not change at all. (This is for the previous model structure, not the bottleneck +GAP approach)

Comment: Sounds like your network is not learning anymore. Did you try to use a different learning rate? Do you use a validation set?

Comment: How many frequency bins in your spectrogram? What is the kernel size of the first conv layer? You should apply 2d convolutions, and enough layers and downsampling that the output before passing to the fully connected is essentially 1 in the temporal dimension